# Join of 2 tables even if id is missing in 2nd table

Tags: sql

In my first Table which is a result of calculations before i got names of some Items. In my 2nd Table i got all translations (de, en, ...). Problem is there are missing some of the translations and Id´s.
My Code

```
SELECT
    R.id,
    R.name,
    R.count,
    limit2,
    max_ts AS reset_ts,
    ts AS lastcount_ts,
    estimation,
    TL.text as translate
FROM
    relevant_data R
LEFT JOIN 
    identifier_texts TL
    ON
        TL.identifier_id = R.id
    WHERE
        TL.language = 'de'
```

If id´s are missing the result is Nothing. So is there a way to say if id is missing take another value for example the original text without translation.
I´ve tried it with NOT EXISTS and anything else nothing worked.

Result if all id´s available:

```
id      name        count       limit2  reset_ts            lastcount_ts  estimation    translate
3314    PunchPSU1   11863421    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    Querstanze (KHE) 1
3315    PunchPSU2   11863436    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    Querstanze (KHE) 2
3316    PunchPSU3   12118854    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    Querstanze (KHE) 3
3317    PunchPSU4   12119034    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    Querstanze (KHE) 4
```

so if id is missing or all result could be like this

```
id      name        count       limit2  reset_ts            lastcount_ts  estimation    translate
3314    PunchPSU1   11863421    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    PunchPSU1
3315    PunchPSU2   11863436    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    PunchPSU2
3316    PunchPSU3   12118854    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    PunchPSU3
3317    PunchPSU4   12119034    800000  25.02.2020 11:44    07.07.2020    2020-03-05    PunchPSU4
```

or translation is emtpy i dont care.
There must be a way to do so. Searched nearly eveything but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the criteria on the second table in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT
    R.id,
    R.name,
    R.count,
    limit2,
    max_ts AS reset_ts,
    ts AS lastcount_ts,
    estimation,
    TL.text as translate
FROM relevant_data R
LEFT JOIN identifier_texts TL
    ON TL.identifier_id = R.id AND TL.language = 'de';
```

The problem with your current query is that the `WHERE` restriction happens *after* the join.  As a result, the restriction on `language` to German, when in the `WHERE` clause, would cause records not having German to be filtered off prematurely.  Using the version I gave above gets around this problem, and retains all records on the left side of the join, even if they do not match.

Comment: Doesn't that leave null values where there is no match in the table on the right side of the join?

Comment: `or translation is emtpy i dont care` ... if the data be missing, then it isn't there and you get NULLs.  Life works this way sometimes.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem.